# Hide macros from other headers

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this:

```
// test.h

namespace test {
    #define TEST_DEBUG !NDEBUG

    class TestClass {
        #if TEST_DEBUG
             // ...
        #endif
    };
}
```

The problem is that other files that include `test.h` will also get the `TEST_DEBUG` macro, which is not ideal.

If I use `#undef` at the end of the header, then that means I can't use the macro in `test.cpp`.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: The power of macro is indispensable and can't be simply replaced regardless of what B. Stroustrup says.

Comment: @metablaster I understand macros are irreplaceable, I'm just asking what to do in this case

Comment: You need to learn about code design, I suggest you to study following PDF book: "API Design for C++" by Martin Reddy

Comment: What about a `constexpr` variable instead of using `#define` and an `if constexpr` instead of testing with `#if` https://onlinegdb.com/hSg60Wojpe

Comment: In this case, I would simply do away with the `TEST_DEBUG` macro, and test the `NDEBUG` macro directly.     If you must use the `TEST_DEBUG` directly, then options are (1) set it in every source file (before including the headers)  (2)  set it in a common header that is included by every other header that needs it (before they test it)  (3)  do it with build/compilation options  e.g. `g++ -DTEST_DEBUG ....`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah you can't do that in global scope, which is where most macros go, and you can't do it within class scope either.

Comment: @metablaster  He had the #define in the "test" namespace so I thought he only wanted it only visible in that namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'd advise avoiding macros in C++ (eg this could be replaced with a bool parameter to the function), the simplest way to achieve this is to define TEST_DEBUG in test.cpp before including test.h, and removing it from test.h.

A #include directive is replaced by the c preprocessor similar to a "copy the contents of that file here" way. This copy is repeated each time the #include appears. This also means if there's something defined before the #include appears in one file, but that's not defined in another, then things may break in unpredictable ways (because eg one file thinks an object is bigger than another file thinks it is).

However, to give more idiomatic c++, for a compile time flag you can use bool constexprs. Alternatively, for a runtime change, if it's a class, pass a bool to the constructor to indicate the difference, a function can have an extra parameter that defaults to false, etc.

Comment: @davidbak I've edited my answer a bit, but it currently says that...

Comment: But in fact you may link things perfectly well together (as the linker does not check the size, the mangled names are the same, sizes are the same but signatures of methods are subtly different - e.g., different expressions for a default parameter, etc.) but it fails in unpredictable ways at runtime ...

Comment: Fair. I've amended the answer to say things may break unpredictably, rather than specifically linker errors as an example.

Comment: I used to have a manager with a very similar name to your handle, I wondered for a moment if you were him trolling me.